# Finding linear dependence step by step?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let
$X = [1 ,2 ,3]$,
$Y = [4, 1 ,5]$ and 
$Z = [2 ,-3, -1]$ be three vectors.

Matrix in Row Echelon form:
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & -2 & | & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & | & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & | & 0
\end{pmatrix}

Thus, $X = 2z$, $Y = -z$ and $Z = z$.

I dont know how to go from there to this answer given to me:
$Z = -2x + y$.

I know this is really simple step but I do not know this step. And I'm kinda stuck.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you have that your vectors satisfy

$$Z-2X=[0,-7,-7];$$
$$Y-4X=[0,-7,-7].$$

Thus, you can say that $$Z-2X=Y-4X$$
which is equal to say that $$Z=Y-2X.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\
4&1&5\\
2&-3&-1\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-4R_1\\R_3-2R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\
0&-7&-7\\
0&-7&-7\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_3-R_2}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&2&3\\
4&-7&-7\\
0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

Remember: the first row represents $\;X\;$ , the second one $\;Y\;$ and the third one $\;Z\;$ , so we got:

$$\text{First step:}\;R_2:\;\;Y-4X\;,\;\;R_3: \;Z-2X$$

$$\text{Second step:}\;R_3 = Z-2X-(Y-4X)=0\implies Z=-2X+Y$$

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you use column vectors. Do forward and backward elimination:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & -3 \\
3 & 5 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & -7 & -7 \\
0 & -7 & -7
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & -7 & -7
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The first steps should be clear; the last one is “sum to the first row the second row multiplied by $-4$”.

This immediately yields that $Z=-2X+Y$, because row operations don't change linear relations between columns.